# Como declarar e passar uma variável decimal de XAML para C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms, xaml

```
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Digite um Valor:" 
               Margin="10"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"
               VerticalOptions="Start"/>

        <Entry Keyboard="Numeric"/>
 <Button Text="Calcular"
                TextColor="White"
                FontSize="Medium"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                BackgroundColor="Accent"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                Clicked="Handle_Clicked"/>
</StackLayout>
```

---

```
namespace App4
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    { 
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private async void Handle_Clicked (object sender,  System.EventArgs e)
        {
           await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Você quer acessar o valor do Entry no código, é isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para acessar o valor do seu `Entry`, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
<Entry 
    x:Name="txtValue"
    Keyboard="Numeric"/>
```

Note que usei a propriedade `x:Name` para definir um nome para o seu `Entry`. Fazendo isso, é possível agora acessar o elemento no seu código.

```
namespace App4
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    { 
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Handle_Clicked (object sender,  System.EventArgs e)
        {
           // Valor do Entry
           var value = txtValue.Text;

           await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
        }
    }
}
```

Para converter o valor para `double`, você pode fazer isto:

```
double newValue = Double.Parse(value);
```

Para converter o valor para `decimal`, você pode fazer isto:

```
decimal newValue = Decimal.Parse(value);
```